# How to remove items from a list where partial matches for items exist in the list

Tags: python, list

If I have a list that contains items within it that have partial matches of other items in the list, such as below where `'bob'` is a partial match within `'bob1'` and `'bob2'`, I want to remove these items with partial matches (`'bob1'`, `'bob2'`, `'peter2'`)
e.g. I want to go from this:

```py
lst = ['bob', 'bob1', 'bob2', 'peter', 'peter2']`
```

to this:

```py
lst = ['bob', 'peter']
```

I have this that works, but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way?

```py
lst = ['bob', 'bob1', 'bob2', 'peter', 'peter2']

removeIndices = []
for i, itemi in enumerate(lst):
    for j, itemj in enumerate(lst):
        if itemi in itemj and itemi != itemj:
            removeIndices.append(j)

for i in sorted(removeIndices, reverse=True):
    del lst[i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all()` with a list that accumulates the result:

```py
result = []

for item in lst:
    if all(substr not in item for substr in result):
        result.append(item)
```

This outputs:

```py
['bob', 'peter']
```

This has two advantages over your existing approach:

1. There's no need to repeatedly call `del` on the original list. If you want to retain the original list, you can. (Repeatedly calling `del` is also quite slow.)
2. A double `for` loop isn't necessary. This syntax is (in my opinion) much cleaner and more intuitive.

Comment: That looks much nicer! I knew there would be a faster way as nested fors was slow as balls! That was HEAPS faster, Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The solution by @BrokenBenchmark works only for sorted lists. Here is a solution that works for unsorted lists as well.

```
lst = ['peter2', 'bob2', 'bob', 'bob1', 'peter']

[item for item in lst if sum(substr not in item for substr in lst)==len(lst)-1]
```

Output:

```
['bob', 'peter']
```